# connect android device to local server xampp

Tags: android, xampp, localhost

I have an android application which takes data from the local server. I works properly on the emulator. But i need help as to how i can achieve this on the device itself. I have tried using the ipv4 but xampp gives a error which states

```
Access forbidden!

New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".
```

I am not sure how i can configure it so that the device can use this address.

Thanks

Comment: What local server? Is this on your computer?

Comment: ya and i want to connect my mobile phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the phone needs to be on the local network (via wifi) or you need to change your httpd-xampp.conf to allow non-local clients to connect to your server, if it's accessible from outside of the network (I doubt it is).

Comment: What IP does your computer have? What IP does your phone have? How are you trying to access your local xampp server?